# Eclipse memory consumption

Tags: java, eclipse

I've noticed that running Eclipse Luna takes out quite a bit of memory (>800 MB) which apparently I cannot afford on my laptop.

I edited the eclipse.ini to limit the memory usage at startup, here it is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m
```

I edited just the last rows for memory usage.

Now the memory usage appears to be less (442.000 Kb currently declared in task manager) but still far higher than the supposed 256 MB that I configured in eclipse.ini.

Can anybody tell me what I am getting wrong here?

Comment: Why is --launcher.XXMaxpermSize 256m in there twice?

Comment: What you're getting wrong is trying to run Eclipse without enough memory. Just because you're specifying the max heap size as 256M doesn't mean there won't be memory used for other things (such as the VM process itself). In any case, running Eclipse on such low specs will make it slow, and if you intend to do anything serious, you will see Eclipse running out of memory.

Comment: @DavidtenHove It doesnt makes a difference to have a launch argument twice

Comment: There's nothing wrong, its just what the -Xmx parameter *does* and what you *expect* are two different worlds. Xmx just controls the heap size, but the heap isn't the only thing in a java VM.

Comment: @Durandal, thanks that makes perfect sense. So I'll probably not to be able to go lower than this.

Comment: @Kayaman you may be right, but so far it is holding (just running 2 fairly light wars on a WebLogic server) and my laptop is "working", which was not with 400 Mb more consumption from Eclipse :)